# How do I make a button shape a custom Path in WPF?

Tags: wpf, button, path, shapes

I have a button using the ControlTemplate below.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
            <Path x:Name="ButtonPath" Fill="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource ArrowBackgroundColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                  Data="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ArrowPathSelector}}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0 0 -35 0"></Path>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource ApplicationFont}" FontSize="{StaticResource Heading3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="35 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

but when I click the Button in my app it is not outlining the Path but instead the original Button.

I cant quite figure out how to get the button to reflect the Path itself.  Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting the button's `Template="{StaticResource ControlTemplate}"`?

Comment: Yes I am.  The problem is when I hover over the button or click it the outline is over a rectangular button and I would like it to be the Path that I am using which is an arrow.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If you are overriding the button's `Template`, then there is nothing to give it a rectangular outline--that comes from the original template, which you are replacing.  Are you embedding this within *another* button?  Can you verify the template is being applied, e.g., does the path show up at all?

Comment: yes the Path shows up.  <Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Template="{StaticResource ControlTemplate}" Foreground="White" Height="50">

Comment: Wait, is the rectangular outline you are referring to the normal button border, or is it the **focus rectangle** (the dotted rectangle that indicates keyboard focus)?

Comment: Oh yes, its actually only showing when I hover over the button.  Is there a way to make that outline the Path itself?

Comment: Yes to what?  Is it the focus rectangle or the normal button border?  Or is it the entire button chrome, background and all?

Comment: its just the focus rectangle, when I hover over it outlines a rectangle below the Path layer it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the shape of the focus rectangle (the dotted border indicating keyboard focus), you need to create a custom `FocusVisualStyle` that draws a dotted path in the same shape as your button content:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusRectangle" TargetType="Control">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Path Stroke="Black"
              StrokeDashArray="2 2"  
              Data="M 0,0 50,50 100,0 Z"
              Stretch="UniformToFill"
              Margin="0 0 -35 0" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then, on the button, set `FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ButtonFocusRectangle}"`.  Note that it would probably be cleaner to define a custom `Style` for the button, and have it apply both the `Template` and `FocusVisualStyle` for you.

Alternatively, you can just get rid of the focus visual entirely by setting `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"`.  You might opt to do this, and simply draw a focus hint in your regular `Template` by, for example, changing the path's stroke with an `IsKeyboardFocused` trigger.

As an aside, you probably want to set `Stretch` to `Uniform` on the paths in both templates.  `UniformToFill` can cause clipping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your Path and your textblock the other way around:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="{StaticResource ApplicationFont}" FontSize="{StaticResource Heading3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="35 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White"/>
        <Path x:Name="ButtonPath" Fill="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource ArrowBackgroundColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
              Data="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ArrowPathSelector}}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0 0 -35 0"></Path>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```